# IE EDGE "pointer-events: none" not working on span tag

Tags: javascript, css, microsoft-edge

In IE EDGE when `pointer-events: none;` is applied to a span tag it doesn't seem to be working, when adding a javascript click event the e.target is the span and not the parent.

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent>     
    <div class="child"><span class="the-span">Something in a span blah blah</span></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.child span {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    console.info(e.target);
});
```

Full Codepen example:
https://codepen.io/JoeHastings/pen/gWgzgK

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It appears to be a confirmed issue with EDGE:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8295099/

To solve the issue in the meantime a block level element like a `div` can be used instead of `span`, or applying `display: inline-block;`, or some other block level display, to an inline element.

Comment: Good old Microsoft. Still trying after all these years.

Comment: This is ludicrous.
Btw, the issue applies to <a> as well.
Setting "display: inline-block" fixed the issue.